Proof of the generalized additive interval property of definite integral
I was trying to prove that for any real number c this equality
$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx$
holds true.
So I started by assuming that a primitive of the function f(x) exists and I called it F(x). That is
$F'(x)=f(x)$
Then I said
$\int_a^c f(x)dx=\left.F(x)\right\rvert_a^c=F(c)-F(a)$
And
$\int_c^b f(x)dx=\left.F(x)\right\rvert_c^b=F(b)-F(c)$
Then when I add those two equalities I get
$\int_a^c f(x)dx+\int_c^b f(x)dx=F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c)=F(b)-F(a)=\left.F(x)\right\rvert_a^b=\int_a^b f(x)dx$
I know my argument isn't that rigorous but can we find a more rigorous proof?

I think you need to break the integrals into their Riemann Sum equivalents then prove the sum follows.

Easiest way is to extend $f$ by $0$ off of $[\min(a, b, c), \max(a, b, c)]$ and use $\int_{a}^{b}f(x),dx = \int_{-\infty}^{b}f(x),dx - \int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x),dx$. Actually, this approach isn't really different from yours if we put $F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y}f(x),dx$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133936/understanding-a-property-of-the-riemann-integral?rq=1

If $f$ isn't continuous it may not have a primitive.  Then what?

I will limit my argument to functions continuous everywhere. I can't say anything about discontinuous functions.
